# Queue items in list with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, indexing, queue

I am using this code in my click event handler that would return a second item in a list.

```
private void nextbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sectorId = new QuizArgs
    {
        sector = "Food Production",

        question = 2,
        Total = 0
    };

    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Quiz), sectorId);
}
```

The quiz page displays a question. There are 5 questions in the list, and they must be displayed one at a time.

So when the first is loaded in the quiz page, and the `nextbtn` is clicked, it should reload the quiz page with the second question in the list, and so forth until the last question.

The quiz page is loaded using this code

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{    
     QuizArgs args = navigationParameter as QuizArgs;
     var SectorGroups = QuizDataSource.GetGroups(args.sector);
     this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = SectorGroups;
}
```

`Object navigationParameter` represents the same three items in the sender object as in the click event. The three items are passed from page to page.

When the button is clicked, it should should go to the quiz page and load the second question.

The `question` item in `sectorId`, should represent the current question to displayed. This item should be passed from page to page to keep track of the questions in the list. Queuing the questions list.

How do I do this, queue the questions in the list so that they are displayed one ta a time, sequentially, via the button click?

The list of questions is defined as

```
private ObservableCollection<QuizGroups> _allQuizGroups = new ObservableCollection<QuizGroups>();

public ObservableCollection<QuizGroups> AllQuizGroups
{
    get { return this._allQuizGroups; }
}
```

Comment: are you using the queue collection type? or does it not matter what order they appear in?

Comment: No I am not using the queue collection type. The order is according to id. First question1, when next button clicked, show question2, next button then shows question3 etc.

Comment: Updated, hope this helps you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would set a property and set it on your `OnClick` when you load the first question. Then, you can call the next question from your list like below.
If you load question zero from a different method set CurrentQuestionEnumerator to zero and use the below method.

```
private int CurrentQuestionEnumerator { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<QuizGroups>  AllQuestions { get; set; }

private void nextbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sectorId = new QuizArgs
    {
        sector = "Food Production",
        question = AllQuestions[CurrentQuestionEnumerator++],
        Total = 0
    };
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Quiz), sectorId);
}
```

Comment: Please see the edit to the question with some additional code. Would `QuestionList`, be what is in my question as `QuizGroups`?

Comment: @user1684586 is quizgroups a collection of questions? or a collection of collections? the name suggests a collection of collections..

Comment: It is a collection questions, and each question has a collection of answers. Does this help?

Comment: Then yes, QuestionList will be quizgroups. However you should consider changing the name since it implies a collection of groups.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this now, but would using an index be possible/better?

Comment: `CurrentQuestionEnumerator` is an integer, Which is calling a specific item in your collection of questions... by inputting a number in `[]` is calling a specific index in the collection... "Indexing" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx. You should put a little time in to reading about c# and .NET